# How do I disable a button if a string is both empty or only has whitespace in it, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, button, whitespace

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.expanding').on('keyup',function() {

        var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
        var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');

        if(textarea.value == '') {
            $('#submit-btn').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#submit-btn').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's my code so far. It works fine, but it's missing a feature. So by default, the value of the textarea is an empty string and therefore the button is disabled. However, any whitespace entered enables the button, which I don't want.

Do I use else if? Or an or in the if statement? How do I write this?

Thanks.

Comment: if($.trim(textarea.value) == '')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [trim()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp):

```
if(textarea.value.trim() == '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the .trim() or $.trim() functions below, strip out the leading & ending whitespaces and then check to see if textarea has a string length (which it won't if it was just a bunch of spaces).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.expanding').on('keyup',function() {

    // Using vanilla javascript
    var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].trim();
    // or with jQuery
    var textarea = $.trim(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]);

    var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');

    if( !textarea.length ) {
        $('#submit-btn').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#submit-btn').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('#submit-btn').prop('disabled', !textarea.length);` (to be more concise)

Answer (score 0):

Just strip leading and trailing whitespace off the value:

```
    if(textarea.value.replace(/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/, "$1") == '') {
```